# Shared models between WebApi and MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm making a project that uses both WebAPI and ASP.NET MVC templates. My MVC sends requests to the WebAPI where the logic happens. For my WebAPI, I have created request/response models (they are used in the services). I need an advice, if it's worth to share this request/response models for WebAPI and MVC, or if there are some good practises to do such things. Thanks!

Comment: Do they need to use the same models? Will this eliminate duplicate code without introducing issues? I think you can think through these issues yourself without asking us.

Comment: You are "us" ? This is a very open question, and I wanted to know the views of others on this subject. Your comment helped the most for sure :) Next time do not waste your keyboard's life.

Comment: I am one of us. This is a community moderated website, and the question has been deemed to be not a good fit for our site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, good practice for design when you are dealing with an API and MVC is separation. Typically you would have your API completely segregated from anything else front end or client wise, as think about it, an API is a self contained system. Like any API such as Google Maps API, theoretically you could call it from a mobile app, a web application, or another separate system so you define expectations for requests and it's up to each client to match the outgoing request model.

MVC models, in the base interpretation, should be for displaying information on the client, so they should be specific to each view and what the view needs, hence view model. You may need some or all of the data to display that an API sends so it's good practice to have the model fit only what the view needs, rather than have a bunch of data in memory that you possibly will never use.

In general, I find a good approach to be have a core project framework which has shared models which match the database, data models. You can use these base definitions, think an Address model which matches a database table which will not change in meaning, to create API models in the service layer for requests/response and data access, and additionally use in definition of view models. Shared core resources but completely separate models which fit the definition of what you are doing in that application layer.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a very common situation in Micro-Service architecture.  Generally, it is best to decouple your front end from your back end, much the same way an app is when calling any other api (e.g. Spotify's api).  But if you do decouple them then you will need to have a copy of the request and response objects in the calling app as well as the api.  They don't have to be *exactly* the same but they need to be close enough to send the request with all required info, and then catch the response and deserialize it back into the object you need in the front end.

The down side is that you end up having to change models two places every time a change has to happen.  That or you start creating versioned routes and gradually deprecate the old ones.